# validation summary in mvc 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to mvc I am trying simple validation summary but the validation summary is not showing in UI.IS there any syntax wrong.

```
   @{Html.ValidationSummary();}
    @{Html.BeginForm();}

    <p>
        Name:-@Html.TextBox("Name")
    </p>
    <p>
        Age:-@Html.TextBox("Age")
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
    <h6>SignIn</h6>
    @{Html.EndForm();}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourActionName", "YourControllerName","Upload", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false);
    <p>
        Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    </p>
    <p>
        Age: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age)
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
    <h6>SignIn</h6>
}
```

...Assuming that you have validation attributes (e.g. `[Required]`) on the properties on the model.

Notice that the validation summary  is *inside* the `Html.BeginForm()` block.

Also notice the `TextboxFor` syntax (rather than `Textbox`) which makes sure that your properties are strongly typed.

Also, make sure you have these settings in the appsettings section of your web.config file:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"></add>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"></add>
```

Comment: ALso I found When I use  @{Html.ValidationSummary();} errors are not showing but when I use @Html.ValidationSummary(); errors are displaying so. when to enclose with "{"

Comment: In the above code, the @Html.ValidationSummary() is already inside the {} from the using statement, so they don't need to be added again.