# Razor: how can I set a class in ValidationSummary?

Tags: razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, validationsummary

I would like to set in a `ValidationSummary` a bootstrap class of error.

How can I do it?

Comment: May be this Answer is Helpful [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19432744/6225452)

Comment: Adding Custom Class `@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })`

Answer (score 0):

@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })